# Finding two central observations in an SAS data step with only one set statement

Tags: sas, center

I am currently taking an SAS programming course, and the teacher has assigned a homework problem which involves taking an excel spreadsheet and reading off the two central observations.  This is not difficult, I have included code that does it.  But he requires that I do it with only *one* SET statement.  I need one SET statement to read the data to begin with, and another to access the POINT= option, at least that's what the SAS website says when they give the example.  So I can't come up with a way to do it with less than two.  Can anyone see a way to remove one SET statement?

```
data selection;
    set gender nobs = y;
   do  z = (y/2) to (y/2)+1;
     set gender point = z;
     output;
   end;
   drop x;
   stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I don't see the harm in having a second set statement the way you've written it, as it only executes once, to get the `nobs` value.

If you really want to do this, I'd say that a silly constraint calls for a silly solution:

```
data selection;
   dsid = open("sashelp.class");
   y    = attrn(dsid,"nobs");
   do  z = (y/2) to (y/2)+1;
     set sashelp.class point = z;
     output;
   end;
   stop;
run;
```

The `open` and `attrn` functions are more commonly used in macro code (via `%sysfunc`) - it's unusual to need them in a data step.

P.S. if you're really keen, it's also possible to do this with zero set statements, but that would involve excessively gratuitous use of macro code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use the `point=` option, you can just loop through the entire data set and only output the records you want.

(This creates the same data set at @user667489 example with `open()` and `attrn()`).

```
data selection2;
set sashelp.class nobs=y;

if floor(y/2) <= _n_ <= floor(y/2)+1 then
    output;
run;
```

Comment: yes, you can also add a `STOP;` when `_N_ > floor(y/2)+1`.